# How did I hide a Microsoft excel 2003 formula?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2003

I have a problem with a spreadsheet that I have had for some years and cannot recall how I managed to set up the condition that the formula takes.

I keep a record of fuel costs whereby I enter the number of liters in one column and it automatically converts to gallons in the next column. When the cells are blank there is no sign of the formula in the gallon column but when I enter the liters it coverts with the formula now showing in the gallon column.

Any Ideas out there?

Comment: You want to know what formula is on the sheet? Or you want a new formula?

Comment: Is the issue that you hid the formula so that it isn't visible when liters is empty?  Where do you not see the formula (in the gallons cell when you click on that cell or in the edit window)?

Answer (score 1):

Highlight one of the cells in the 'gallons' column that has data in it , either look up in the formula bar (above the spreadsheet) or

To view the formula in Excel 2003, a short cut according to the [Microsoft support page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/display-or-hide-formulas-HP005199811.aspx) is to

> Press CTRL + ` (grave accent).

Pressing it again will return to the values